# How do I setup passwordless ssh on AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

How do I setup passwordless ssh between nodes on AWS cluster

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following steps to setup password less authentication are tested thoroughly for Centos and Ubuntu.

**Assumptions:**

1. You already have access to your EC2 machine. May be using the pem key or you have credentials for a unix user which has root permissions.
2. You have already setup RSA keys on you local machine. Private key and public key are available at "~/.ssh/id_rsa" and "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" respectively.

**Steps:**

1. Login to you EC2 machine as a root user.
2. Create a new user

   ```
   useradd -m <yourname> 
   sudo su <yourname>
   cd 
   mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   Append contents of file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on you local machine to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on EC2 machine.

   ```
   chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
   ```
3. Make sure sshing is permitted by the machine. In file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, make sure that line containing "PasswordAuthentication yes" is uncommented. Restart sshd service if you make any change in this file:

   ```
   service sshd restart # On Centos
   service ssh restart # On Ubuntu
   ```
4. Your passwordless login should work now. Try following on your local machine:

   ```
   ssh -A <yourname>@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
   ```
5. Making yourself a super user. Open `/etc/sudoers`. Make sure following two lines are uncommented:

   ```
   ## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
   %wheel ALL=(ALL)       ALL

   ## Same thing without a password
   %wheel ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```

   Add yourself to wheel group.

   ```
   usermod -aG wheel <yourname>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

This may help someone

Copy the pem file on the machine then copy the content of pem file to the .ssh/id_rsa file you can use bellow command or your own

```
cat my.pem > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

try ssh localhost it should work and same with the other machines in the cluster

Comment: Running CentOS 6.5 in Amazon AWS EC2. This works perfectly!!

Comment: just need to add username as well when accessing from Mac Terminal

Answer (score 1):

how I made Paswordless shh work between two instances is the following:

- create ec2 instances – they should be in the same subnet and have the same security group
- Open ports between them – make sure instances can communicate to each other. Use the default security group which has one rule relevant for this case:

  - Type: All Traffic
  - Source: Custom – id of the security group
- Log in to the instance you want to connect from to the other instance
- Run:
  `1 ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa`
  to generate a new rsa key.
- Copy your private AWS key as ~/.ssh/my.key (or whatever name you want to use)
- Make sure you change the permission to 600
  `1 chmod 600 .ssh/my.key`
- Copy the public key to the instance you wish to connect to passwordless
  `1 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -i ~/.ssh/my.key ubuntu@10.0.0.X "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`
- If you test the passwordless ssh to the other machine, it should work.
  `1 ssh 10.0.0.X`

Answer (score -5):

you can use ssh keys like described here:
http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/