# Setup passwordless SSH using a script

Tags: shell, ssh, installation

I need to setup passwordless SSH on a list of hosts using a shell script and a provided password for the user.

I'm not sure which way would be the best to do it. I though about using expect but I don't like the way to "hack" into an interactive session. Is there any other way to do it?

The setup script needs to be very stable on Red Hat and SUSE.

Comment: Have you looked into ssh keys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594048/how-do-i-setup-passwordless-ssh-on-aws accepted answer provides a pretty good link about how to do this.

Comment: I know the process of using public and private ssh keys to login without password. But I have to write a script that does all the setup. Therefore I need to interact with the commands, which I don't like.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514405/how-to-automate-password-entry/9439027#9439027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a program that does this: ssh-copy-id.  Of course you do need to give it the appropriate password; a well-worn tool for this is the program "expect."

Comment: That's what I already thought off. But it's not very nice because you have to handle all the interaction with the commands, which might be a problem in some cases. Especially when you have command that produce output in different languages on different machines.

Comment: expect will handle the interaction for the most part.  If you want this to work internationally then maybe you have a hard way ahead of you.  If you had thought of this before you should have put it in your original post.